# I have a background set to the bottom of the screen, but when I go to full screen there is an empty white space beneath. Why is this happening?

Tags: html, css, background, whitespace

The background of the body is set background-attachment: fixed; and background-position: left bottom; This works great when the window is maximized, but when I go to full screen, there's an empty white space at the bottom. Here's the code:

html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css" />
<script type = "text/javascript" src="script.js">
</script>
    <div id = "container">
        <body onLoad="baseSize()">
        <div id = "head">
            <div id = "icon"><p>Craig InTheDell</p></div>
        </div>
        <div id = "navcol">
            <table>
                <tr><td><a href = "poetry.html">Poetry</a></td></tr>
                <tr><td><a href = "essays.html">Essays</a></td></tr>
                <tr><td><a href = "stories.html">Stories</a></td></tr>
                <tr><td><a href = "about.html">About</a></td></tr>
            </table>
        </div>
            </body>
    </div>
</html>
```

css

```
html {
    font-family: "Times New Roman";
}
body {
    background-image: url(treeshort.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left bottom;
}
#container {
    font-size: 16px;
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: auto;
}
#head {
    height: 100px;
}

#icon {
    font-size: 50px;
    float: right;
}
table {
    position: absolute;
    left: 950px;
    font-size: 40px;
}
a {
    color: #000000;
}
```

I also have some javascript that sets #container height to the availHeight of the window.

```
function baseSize() {
    var available = window.screen.availHeight;

    var container = document.getElementById("container");
    container.style.height = available + "px";
}
```

Comment: Put all your visible html inside the body tag

Comment: It's hard to be of help when the posted CSS and HTML are not as described in the question. Placing your `body` tag inside a container `div` is odd, your `body` tag does not have its CSS set to `background-attachment: fixed;`, and even setting it does not result in anything which I would describe as 'works great'. You are not explaining the desired result in your question.

Answer (score 0):

First, fix the errors in your HTML. They look terrible.

Then, you calculate the height as `screen.availHeight`. That's a mistake, `availHeight` is the height of the desktop. Excluding things like taskbars and whatever you may have on your computer. What you need is `screen.height`.